# Can I find remaining 85-90 columns which was not provided to me? in databricks

Tags: sql, sql-server, databricks-sql, aws-databricks

I have a table in Databricks which has almost 100's columns. I was given with some 10-15 columns, can I find remaining 85-90 columns which was not provided to me?

For example, Table 'A has column name like (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,....z), I was given with (a,f,h)

I have to find (b,c,d,e,g,i.....z)

Comment: Query `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`..?

Comment: Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Comment: can you give full query